# Picard Group Can Contain rational curve?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

X is a smooth projective curve with genus>2

My Question is, Pic(X) can contain rational curve(P^1) or not

Comment: No, because $Pic^0(X)$ is an abelian variety.

Answer (score 3):

Like Donu Arapura said in the comments:

> No, because $\mathrm{Pic}^{0}(X)$ is an abelian variety.

To complete the argument: abelian varieties don't contain rational curves, precisely because the genus of a rational curve is $0$. Every map from a curve of genus $g$ to an abelian variety factors via the Albanese of the curve (an abelian variety of dimension $g$, dual to the Jacobian). Hence every map from a rational curve to an abelian variety factors via a point.

Comment: A more elementary argument: every map from a group variety to an abelian variety becomes a homomorphism after a translation. The projective line becomes a group under addition when one point is removed, and a group under multiplication when two points are removed, and so we get contradictory statements.

Comment: Or a different elementary argument, in characteristic zero: An abelian variety has enough global $1$-forms to generate the cotangent space at every point. They would have to pull back to global $1$-forms on $\mathbb{P}^1$, and all such $1$-forms are zero. So the map has vanishing differential at every point and (in characteristic zero) is constant.